# 17.10 suspend not available

Tags: suspend

At latest version 17.10, a suspend (hibernate) 
function is not available.

Anyone welcome with an idea,
how to make it available again, 
without damaging the system at resume.

Comment: Top right tjere should be a power type button, click it, then press & hold the <ALT> key and the power-off button should change to a PAUSE symbol. The PAUSE option is suspend.  (*sorry this is vague - I'm running XFCE or Xubuntu*)

Comment: Worked fine, so we need an extra pause button. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Top right of the panel there is power-logo button, click it and the power-off symbol will appear.  When you press & hold the  key, the power-off button will change to a PAUSE symbol. The PAUSE option is suspend, so you can now click the pause button and your machine will suspend.

(*sorry this is a little vague, I'm running Xubuntu or XFCE desktop so its from memory*)

Comment: we still need an extra pause button, and unfortunately firebug is not enough to identify the code